# Underground Tunnels in New York City and Boston

Tags: united-states, 18th-century

Where are the underground tunnels built by masons in New York City and Boston in 1760's~1780's? Do they exist till our present day?

Comment: Where did you here about them?

Comment: Skeptics.Stackexchange?

Comment: Is this about the alligators? ;P

Comment: There are still lots of tunnels in Boston and NYC, what specifically about them are you looking to find out about?

Comment: I mean the tunnels that existed during the American Revolution not Subway tunnels

Comment: I could tell you but you didn't pass your Mason initiation yet.

Comment: @DVK this is what it used to be called right? because they were built by masons? Maybe I'm wrong

Answer (score 2):

I've found something:

> Originally, the small building was known as Goff’s Tavern and was rumored to have secret tunnels to which the local English-sympathizing Tories would repair for escape from the Patriots. Later, runaway slaves allegedly used them during the Civil War. So
>   far, those tunnels haven’t been confirmed, but additional archeological digs are planned.
>
> *[Craft Masonry in Orange and Rockland Counties, New York](http://www.omdhs.syracusemasons.com/sites/default/files/history/Craft%20Masonry%20in%20Orange%20and%20Rockland%20Counties.pdf) Page 23*

However, it appears this info was copied directly from [another article](http://www.esmason.com/magpdf/mason_spring_08.pdf)(warning: large file) which goes into much deeper detail about the tavern. However, it says no more about the tunnel. It does not say when the building was constructed, but it does allude to the late 1700s. It is found in Monroe, New York. It could be what you're looking for.